# Message not deleting with m.expunge

Tags: python-3.x, imap, email, imaplib

I have studied numerous questions and answers here and from what I can see my code is correct.  For some reason though, the mail I have selected is not being deleted.

My code is:

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap-mail.outlook.com")
m.login("MY_EMAIL","MY_PWORD")
m.select("Sent")
resp, data = m.uid("search", None, "ALL")
uid = data[0].split()[-1]

#Can also get message content with lines 
# resp,data = m.uid('fetch',uid,"(BODY[HEADER])")  
# print(data)

m.store(uid, "+FLAGS", "\\Deleted")                #Works fine to here
m.expunge()                                        #This doesn't delete message
m.close()
m.logout()
```

If I change the `m.expunge()` line to `print(m.expunge())` I get the tuple

> ('OK', [None])

The message is still in the mailbox even with the "OK" response.
I'm unsure why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using UIDs to identify the messages, so you also need to use UID commands to change the \Deleted flag:

```
m.uid('STORE' uid, "+FLAGS", "\\Deleted")
```

You are currently trying to set the deleted flag on Message Sequence Number with the same UID, which probably doesn't exist, or refers to a completely different message.